# SOX in iPhone For Audio Conversion

Tags: ios, audio, caf, audio-converter

I want to implement conversion of `.caf` file to any other format of audio. I heard about `sox`. But i did not find any suitable reference or any code about how to implement it. Anyone having an idea??

Comment: The docs are here: http://sox.sourceforge.net/libsox.html You might also want to check out libsndfile

Comment: Sorry , i didn't mentioned it in my question. But i want to implement this in iPhone.

Comment: Either way, soxlib and libsndfile are written in c and should work perfectly in that environment.

Comment: Can i get the perfect library for converting `.caf` file to any other format. i am just so much confused. Or any other way to convert it.

Comment: Well it depends on your definition of "perfect". Keep in mind that caf is a container format, so no library is guaranteed to be able to read all caf files. Moreover, you simply can't expect any library, especially a free one, to support exporting to "any other format". So you'll have to read the docs and decide for yourself which is *best* for your application. There is no perfect, sorry.

Comment: Ohk. No Problem. Thanks for your valuable suggestion. :)